# BrainBench: программерские сертификаты

Tags: сертификат

Всем привет!

Есть пара вопросов по небезызвестному brainbench

1. Кто-нибудь знает, если купить у них на сайте подписку на месяц ($99), то выходит что я могу выбрать любой программерский тест и прорешивать его столько раз сколько захочу? И после удачной попытки получу заветный сертификат?
2. Можно ли тоже самое сделать с любым другим конкретным тестом (которые идут по $49)?

Comment: а зачем они нужны эти (конкретно эти) сертификаты? у меня вот есть парочка лет 10 им уже или даж больше, но как-то душу не греют )

Comment: хорошая добавка к резюме. наверное не лишнее, особенно если только входишь в специальность

Answer (score 1):

Раньше так можно было сделать, я так и делала. Решаешь много раз один и тот же тест, а потом показываешь самый лучший результат для работодателей.
Один парень в резюме насдавал кучу этих brainbench, а потом в резюме указал, что он топ 5% по c#, топ 7% по ASP.NET и так далее. Не знаю, насколько это ему помогло, но я его по крайней мере запомнила.

Answer (score 1):

Поскольку актуальных данных(2015-2016) на русском кроме этого вопроса особо нет, напишу свое мнение как обладателя той 99$ подписки.

Насколько я для себя понял - эти сертификаты только в очень ограниченном виде считаются HR-господами плюсом, т.к. достаточно легко взять и прорешать конкретные типовые задачи, войдя тем самым в некий топ, не имея при этом положительно никаких реальных знаний.

Совсем другое - когда тестирование проводится без предварительного уведомления непосредственно на собеседовании. Насколько я знаю, как минимум в одной российской компании это есть как первый этап технического собеседования.

Для себя я определил use-case этой платформы примерно следующим образом:

Если ищешь работу, имея < 2 лет опыта, то быстро замечаешь, что каждой первой организации (в интересной мне профобласти) требуется "отличное знание С/С++", причем метрик оного знания в описании вакансии как правило не задано. Таким образом, имеешь 4-5 на brainbench - можно с некоторой долей уверенности говорить о том, что требуемая степень экспертизы плюс-минус есть и идти на собеседование с шансами > 50% на получение работы. [Пруф](https://hh.ru/vacancy/16317638) от ЛК.

P.S. При грамотном подходе стоимость годовой подписки чудесным образом может быть снижена до 67$ за счет промо-кодов `SUMMERSAVE`(применим, кажется, с 28 мая) либо `SAVE70`(применим, кажется, всегда). По крайней мере на май 2016 было актуально.